# Custom tab par in ionic 4 how can I do

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework, ionic4

How can I do something like that([custom tab par](https://dribbble.com/shots/9173685-Creative-Tab-Bar-Animation?utm_source=Clipboard_Shot&utm_campaign=excellentwebworld&utm_content=Creative%20Tab%20Bar%20Animation&utm_medium=Social_Share) ) in ionic 4
[image]

Answer (score 1):

All of the Ionic components are just web components. They were built with tool called [StencilJS](https://stenciljs.com/). You could create a custom tab bar using this tool and publish it on NPM and then import it into your project. Replicating the behavior of the existing tab layout in Ionic could be a difficult task however.

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse the Ionic's UI components and restyle them to do this but the middle curve is tricky to do. I don't think this you can achieve this effect with pure CSS. The simplest solution that I came up with is to draw a svg with the desired curve and place it to the middle of the toolbar. Here is a working [example](https://codepen.io/htmn/pen/JjoLaXw).

```
<ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-button>
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="home"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
      <ion-button>
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="search"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>

    <svg width="200" height="55"></svg>

    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <ion-button>
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="heart-empty"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
      <ion-button>
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="contact"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
</ion-toolbar>

 ion-toolbar {
    --border-width: 0 !important;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
 }

  svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: calc(50% - 100px);
  }
```

I used an online drawing tool to quickly draw the path and fill so it matches the background.